# Reduce Workflow Foundation project build time

Tags: performance, visual-studio, build, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on a WF project which has many processes and code activities in it.
The project takes too long to build (20-30 times more than any other project in the solution).

I've asked google about this, but there seems to be no information.

Please, how can I reduce the build time of a Workflow Foundation project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main part is probably that all XAML based composite activities get validated during build. That means, they get instantiated!

You can turn that off with an undocumented setting in the csproj file:

```
  <SkipWorkflowValidation>true</SkipWorkflowValidation>
  <DisableWorkflowCompiledExpressions>true</DisableWorkflowCompiledExpressions>
```

This setting must be added to all configuration sections (the relevant  elements, typically, you’ll want do to this in all the configurations).

The project file (csproj or vbproj extension) can be edited in Visual Studio by following these steps:

- Right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select “Unload Project”
- Right-click on the unloaded project (now shown with the “(unavailable”) postfix), and select “Edit ”
- The project file opens in the Visual Studio editor and you can manually edit it.

Once you are done editing the file, you can right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select “Reload Project”.

Try that and watch the build time. But be aware, this will skip some tests during build that might be valuable...

Comment: Mindblowing! It worked. Where did you find this please? And, what are the tests that are skipped? Thanks!

Comment: We had a support call at MS where I got this information. We had another problem: Instantiating the activities during build time threw exceptions, because some activities of ours need a special runtime environment to act properly, which is not present at build time. So the build process failed because of this instantiation - even worse than long build times :)

Comment: I'm not sure what MS does with the activities during build in general, from the names of these settings I can only guess that they try to determine at build time that the activity will be runnable without problems later. "Detect problems early" is usually a good pattern.

Comment: Unless you waste number of developers x number of builds per day x 15 seconds time :) A build server which has the 'unoptimized' build configuration can detect problems. And everyone can use the saved time to fix them. *If* there are any. Thanks for your help.